# 'Run' faster than Build/Archive (Xcode/Mac)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, build

I have a weird problem and I don't know what could be wrong.
When I hit 'Run' (the triangle on top) my application runs 10% faster. When I select 'Archive' in the menu and run it from the Terminal it's slower. It's also slow (same speed) when I take the app from 'Products' on the left pane.
It's reproducible. Both, 'Run' and 'Archive' use 'Release' Build Configuration. I don't know where to look for.

macOS Sierra 10.12.3 / Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: What does the app do? How have you determined this?

Comment: I hit a button in my application then it starts a process that takes for example 3 minutes. I take the time before and after with time_t. In this 'process' it does nothing graphical nor GUI things (nearly no GUI things). It's calculations, I use std heaps, std maps, threads, much hard disk write and read. Hard to explain. C++, std, boost.